# Body always empty when answering an invoke

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a live Microsoft Teams application with a couple of working functionalities. Right now I am working on a new feature where the user clicks on a button in a previously sent adaptive card and I will open another adaptive card with a form for the user to fill. I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots) documentation as a base, which has a really similar example as to what I am trying to achieve here.

Since I am working with an adaptive card the button that will open my form card is an `Action.Submit` button with `"msteams": {"type': 'task/fetch"}` inside its data. When I click that button I receive the correct `invoke` call, the body looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "invoke",
  "timestamp": "2021-02-01T20:19:34.327Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2021-02-01T15:19:34.327-05:00",
  "id": "f:955407977095344101",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
  "from": {
    "id": "censured",
    "name": "censured",
    "aadObjectId": "censured"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "tenantId": "censured",
    "id": "censured"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "censured",
    "name": "Tcensured"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "censured",
      "country": "censured",
      "platform": "censured",
      "timezone": "censured",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "censured"
    },
    "source": {
      "name": "message"
    },
    "legacy": {
      "replyToId": "censured"
    }
  },
  "replyToId": "censured",
  "value": {
    "commandId": "reply_feedback",
    "requested_feedback_id": 1,
    "type": "composeExtension/fetchTask"
  },
  "locale": "censured",
  "localTimezone": "censured"
}
```

It seems like the invoke call is correct, so the next step is to answer the call with my adaptive card. However, it doesn't matter what I answer this call with, when I inspect the `invoke` call in my browser the answer is always empty, even if I answer with a really simple task response like (which I got from the documentation)

```
{
  "task": {
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
      "title": "Task module title",
      "height": 500,
      "width": "medium",
      "url": "https://contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer",
      "fallbackUrl": "https://contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer"
    }
  }
}
```

Or even

```
{
    "task": {
        "type": "message",
        "value": "Test"
    }
}
```

I still get an empty response on the front-end side. I am fairly confident that I am properly answering the call on my side with data, I have a lot of other features in this same application working so I don't think it is some problem where I am actually giving an empty body from my side. Maybe for the specific `invoke` call I need to answer things in a different manner?

Obs: I am using Python with no SDKs, so I build Adaptive Cards and interpret the requests on my application.

Comment: Can we discuss this over call? Could you please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Sure, I just sent an email.

Comment: closeing this ticket since you have confirmed in mail that you have solved it already.